# Chrome Extension Messaging help

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

Heres the code: http://pastebin.com/UxhJAdMb

I want to send the getlink.js (chrome content script) variable "found" to a textbox in popup.html

I dont understand the documentation on message passing here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html (new to javascript)

Also, how can I modify this Regex to find all sites staring with like wwww.stackoveflow or http://www.stackoverflow.com

```
var reg = /(https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)/g
```

Comment: Is the regex for Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome messaging is a little confusing at first, but your listener is in the wrong place. You need to first send a request from your contentscript, which in your case is `getlink.js`

```
# contentscript (getlink.js)
// ... code that does stuff here ...

chrome.extension.sendRequest({greeting: 'hello'}, function(response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Then inside your popup.html you can add your listener:

```
# popup.html
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

  // do something with request

  // always send something back, even if it's empty
  sendResponse({});
});
```

Comment: Hey do I replace "response" with the "found" variable?

Comment: Response is used if you decide to send a message back from the script/page that received the request. If you had `sendResponse({message: 'Goodbye.});` in your listener, your contentscript would receive that object back.

Comment: Man I am totally confused (sorry). I dont get whats being sent to popup.html here. what is function(response)? I just want to send the value of the found variable.

Comment: In my example, the javascript object `{greeting: 'hello'}` is being sent to the listener in popup.html. In your case, you just need to replace that with your `found` variable.

Comment: @NoviceCoding - I think this will help. The content page talks to the core files. The core files can then reply to the content page. The messages are sent back and forth as objects. So In scurker's second code block he would call request.greeting and it would be `hello.` He could then do `sendResponse({message: 'Goodbye.});` from the second code block as a reply. Finally the first code block receives the message and can call `response.message` to say `goodbye`. Hope that helps!